# Flutter doctor command

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

I just downloaded and extracted the flutter SDK file, and I also included the bin folder in my environment variables. However, I am unable to get anything back after I run the "flutter doctor" command.

I have restarted my computer and tried other solutions here on Stackoverflow, but all to no avail.

Comment: Please provide the log output you are getting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just recheck your flutter sdk bin path, from my PC "*C:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.16.5-stable\flutter\bin*" is the path of my sdk just copy that and paste in both *path* in **user variable** and **system variable**

I had same problem and above solution works for me !